# Installing android app from PC to device via USB without USB debugging

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to install the app directly from android studio of my PC to any android device without generating apk file and without enabling USB debugging of my device. Is it possible ?

Comment: Use this to install app on your device using browser without cable https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

Answer (score 2):

1) Using Android Studio

You'll have to build your app from the menu: Build > Generate Signed APK
Then from the directory that your .apk was built you can transfer the .apk to your phone and install it (when prompted check "Unknown Sources").

2) (Advanced) Using [Skipsoft Toolkit](http://www.skipsoft.net/?page_id=1197), if your device supports it.

Comment: I'm also not allowed to generate the apk file.
I have also edited my question, pls hv a look at it also and help.
Thanks in advance